# Plot data with quarterly tic marks

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting data that is recorded on the last day of the 3rd, 6th, 9th, and 12th months of the year. I would like the tic marks to be at `03/09, 06/09, ...`

After reading the documentation, I thought this could be done by saying

```
set xtics "03/09", 7889220
```

because there are about 7889220 seconds in three months. But rather than starting with March, 2009, the tic marks start on the next day, shown here (with the remaining part of the plot removed):

[image: Screen capture of x-axis labels]

Is there a way to force the tic marks to be at end of months?

**UPDATED:**

The date format in the input file is `mm/dd/yyyy`, which I am reading with these commands:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"
```

and I'm then doing this:

```
set format x "%m/%y"
set xrange ["03/31/2009":"12/31/2010"]
```

Comment: what format are the time stamps in your data file?

Comment: Yes, this all depends on the format you are using for your time in your data file. Post that and we should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Discussion:

The Gnuplot behaviour when you use `set format x "%m/%y"` will be to place `xtics` at month boundaries since that really is what this command is asking Gnuplot to do.

To solve your problem there may be two posisble approaches that you can take here depending on how large your data set is.

### Approach1:

If you do have time stamps in your data file one possibility is to just use the `xtics` directly for plotting (suitable if you have a large dataset)

So you do away with all the time commands in your script and just use

```
plot 'Mydata.dat' u 2:xtic(1) w points
```

### Approach2:

The other option is to set custom `xtics`, however you will have to do this by hand and if you have a large dataset this might be cumbersome (suitable if the dataset has tens of points)

```
set xtics ("03/09" "03/31/2009", "06/09" "06/30/2009", "09/09" "09/30/2009", "12/09" "12/31/2009")
```

Will give you tics at the exact days you need them to be.

### Assumption:

I assume that the first column in your file are the time stamps and second column are the data values. Below, I show a graph where I use the manual setting approach (Approach 2).

### Result with dummy data:

[image]